# How can I avoid using another promise in my case?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have two .js files like:

index.js:

```
app.get("/testing", (req, res) => {
  testAsyncFunction().then((resolvedData) => {
    res.send(resolvedData);
  });
})
```

and server.js:

```
const asyncFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res('resolved');
    },3000 )
  })
}

const testAsyncFunction = () => {
  return new Promise(async (res) => {
    const result = await asyncFunction();
    return res(result);
  })
}
```

and this is working as intended but if I change the testAsyncFunction(so that I don't create a new promise) to something like this:

```
const testAsyncFunction = async () => {
  const result = await asyncFunction();  
  return result;
}
```

and in index.js:

```
app.get("/testing", (req, res) => {
  res.send(testAsyncFunction());
})
```

I'm getting an empty object because it isn't waiting for 3 seconds, what am I missing in the latter case? I want to avoid creating a new Promise just to wait for another promise.

**UPDATE**

I changed the testAsyncFunctionto something like this:

```
const testAsyncFunction = () => {
  asyncFunction().then((result) => {
    return result;
  })  
}
```

Even though the above function. isn't an async function why do I still have to wait for it in the `index.js`..I'm assuming the returned value won't be a promise in this case so that's the part I'm confused about.

Comment: I think in this scenario you can not avoid "creating another promise" in the `app.get()` callback. You can just hide it using `async/await`.

Comment: Your modification in server.js is correct. You just do not need to modify index.js at all. The original is already correct and the modification is wrong

Comment: you want to wait 3 seconds before sending?  what is the reason to do that?

Comment: @slebetman, Sirko You guys are correct but I don't understand the reason for using .then or await in index.js too... I mean in the latter case I'm not sending a promise so that's a bit confusing.

Comment: @RameshReddy `async` always wrap your returned value into a promise

Comment: @nopole I just created a simple example. I'm resolving after 3 seconds so that it'll simulate an asynchronous behavior. The actual app is a bit complicated.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I've repeated this phrase, I'd be quite wealthy - ***"Every`async` function returns a promise.  You have to use `.then()` or `await` on the return value from an `async` function to get the resolved value."***

Comment: I changed the function(updated my question too) so that it doesn't use any async/await, so why should I `await` or `.then` in my index.js ....do I get a promise in this case too?

Comment: Once a result is obtained asynchronously (like via a promise) anywhere in your function, then the only way to return it to the caller is asynchronously (usually via a promise).  You can return the promise directly or use an `async` function and let JS make the promise for you. But, either way, you're going to be returning a promise and the caller is going to be using `.then()` or `await` to get the value from the promise.  That's just how asynchronous code and promises work in Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 "the only way to return it to the caller is asynchronously (usually via a promise)" this finally cleared my doubt. I hope you find tons of nickels and become wealthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`so that I don't create a new promise` that's how it should be, other way is an antipattern. However, when a function returns a promise you need to wait for the same

```
app.get("/testing", async (req, res) => {
  let obj = await testAsyncFunction()
  res.send(obj );
});
```

OR

```
app.get("/testing", (req, res) => {
  testAsyncFunction().then((obj) => {
    res.send(obj );
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me the reason for using '.then' or 'await' even when I'm not using an async function? as I updated in the question.

Comment: Your updated code will not work `asyncFunction().then((result) => {` should be returned. `return asyncFunction().then((result) => {`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const testAsyncFunction = async () => {
>   const result = await asyncFunction();  
>   return result;
> }
> ```

`async` functions always return promises. So this is equivalent to:

```
const testAsyncFunction = () => {
  return asyncFunction();  
}
```

---

> I want to avoid creating a new Promise just to wait for another promise.

So just use the existing promise:

```
app.get("/testing", (req, res) => {
  asyncFunction().then((resolvedData) => {
    res.send(resolvedData);
  });
})

const asyncFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res('resolved');
    },3000 )
  })
}
```